# How do I make Websphere application server accept url without encoding (Issue only with IE)?

Tags: rest, internet-explorer, websphere, url-encoding

This is an issue only with IE as the browser is not doing the encoding part on it's own. The service has got two query parameters with values containing special characters and spaces. It works well with all browsers except IE. Getting a 400 bad request on IE

Comment: Is there any proxy server in front like IHS/Apache?

Comment: No, my production instance is a Websphere and there are no proxy on it. I have the same issue when hosted on a Dev Tomcat instance as well. But when the service is hosted on a Datapower the url without encoding is accepted

Comment: it is probably canonicalized by DP. Sounds like you need to find a way to avoid these requests in the referer.

Comment: (By referer I mean whatever link or form or whatever ends up generating the failing URL -- pre-encode sonmething or fix it with javascript before submit for example)

Comment: Okay thank you! I will try the client side solution as well. Was also searching for options like AllowEncodedSlashes on server itself